# Array Input using for loop

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I am a beginner in programming. It was taught that arrays store address of the first element. While using for loop when I input the Array elements using `scanf` I should not use `&` character right 
it should be `("%d",Arr[i])` , instead of `("%d",&Arr[i])` .
but why it is showing error?

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641963/3975177

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array type has a special property, in some of the cases, a variable with type array decays to a type as pointer to the first element of the array.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]

However, if the type is not an array type, it does not hold.

From your description, it sounds you have the array defined as

```
int Arr[16];   // 16 is arbitrary, just for example
```

In your case, `Arr` is an array of integers and `Arr[i]` is not an array type, it's an integer. So, you have to pass the address of this integer to `scanf()`.

The correct statement would be

```
 ("%d",&Arr[i]); // passing the address.
```

To compare, if you have an array defined like

```
 char array [16];
```

then you can write

```
 scanf("%15s", array); // 'array' is array type, which is same as `&array[0]` in this case
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe you schould explain that an array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array and what an array-type looks like.

Comment: @Swordfish And how would that be helpful in the context? I explained `Arr[i]` is not a pointer, and it won;t _decay_ to pointer either. That answers the question, is not it?

Comment: I'm concerned about the 2nd sentence of the question and I sense there is a more general confusion with the OP about arrays. But as I said, I didn't donvote and my comments are just my € 0.02.

Comment: @Swordfish Right, I get you're trying to help, and I know you'll not be downvoting for _that_ reason. Maybe someone lost their keys. :)

Comment: I understood, did some research on that. But can you make it clear what 15 means here in scanf("%15s", array)

Comment: @HarshBhudolia it indicates the size to be scanned, here its number of elements -1, the last one reserved for null characters.

Comment: Just to make sure, Doesn't %s already discard the null character while reading?

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow so I might have ignored the procedures, as I am still acquainting myself with the various working of the site